# Issue converting endnote to correct bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I use latex to write all of my assignments, and have previously written my bibliography separately. I started converting endnote to bibtex recently and I am having issues getting correct bibliography, though the in text citations are correct.

Here is my ~relevant~ preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% begin preamble 

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite} %bibtex
\usepackage{natbib}
```

And an example of my citation, which comes out correctly

```
\subsubsection*{Introduction}

In the article `Seafaring as social action' by Helen Farr \citep{RN123}, the author argues exactly as the title describes; seafaring is a social act and therefore should be studied as one...
```

At the end of the document I have this

```
%references list
\pagebreak

\bibliography{exam}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
```

This is how my document comes out. My issue is with this citation as an example - Robb and Farr 2005, where I am citing a chapter of a book.

[image]

It comes out as 'book section' when it should have the following format according to Harvard style citations.

> Farr, Helen, and John Robb. 2005. 'The Archaeology of Mediterranean Prehistory.' in Emma Blake and Arthur Bernard Knapp (eds.), The Archaeology of Mediterranean Prehistory (Blackwell Pub.: Malden, MA).

I have tried Chicago and other citation styles and none of them fix the problem.

Here is a look at my `.bib` file.

```
@inbook{RN139,
   author = {Farr, Helen and Robb, John},
   booktitle = {The Archaeology of Mediterranean Prehistory},
   editor = {Blake, Emma and Knapp, Arthur Bernard},
   publisher = {Blackwell Pub.},
   address = {Malden, MA},
   chapter = {Substances in Motion: Neolithic Mediterranean "Trade"},
   pages = {24-46},
   year = {2005},
   type = {Book Section}
}
```

I need it to properly display the editors for books and separate them from the authors of the book chapters.

Comment: The correct entry type for this sort of entry would be `@incollection` and not `@inbook`. The title of the chapter should go into the `title` field and not into `chapter`. If I change these two things, the output is much closer to what you seem to want, but not identical. (Keep in mind that "Harvard style" refers to a class of author-year citation styles and not to a specific well-defined style like APA style or Chicago style. So different Harvard styles might produce different results.)

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you don't need to load both `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\usepackage{cite}`. You seem to be using `natbib` commands, so I would remove the `\usepackage{cite}`. Furthermore, `utf8x` is usually not needed and often causes more trouble than it is worth. I would just go for `utf8` (which is the default on modern LaTeX systems anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used @incollection not @inbook. Unfortunately endnote does this as a standard so i had to go into the .bib and change in manually.

alternatively you can use book section in endnote. Thanks!